# Playwright test debug not showing browser

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I am trying to debug a test of mine, but it will not pop up the browser. The command "npx playwright test debug" fails and selecting "show browser" in the test panel does not do anything. My playwright test for VSCode is on v1.0.19.

Comment: When using VScode extension, did you run tests using the extension itself or using the box playwright test command?

Answer (score 0):

The command you mentioned misses -- before debug. Use `npx playwright test --debug` instead.